# execute shell command from android

Tags: java, android, xml, shell, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to execute this command from the application emulator terminal (you can find it in google play) in this app i write `su` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, so write:

`screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/MyVideo.mp4`

and press again <kbd>enter</kbd> and start the recording of the screen using the new function of android kitkat.

so, i try to execute the same code from java using this:

```
Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Process execute = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/MyVideo.mp4");
```

But don't work because the file is not created. obviously i'm running on a rooted device with android kitkat installed. where is the problem? how can i solve? because from terminal emulator works and in Java not?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You should grab the standard input of the `su` process just launched and write down the command there, otherwise you are running the commands with the current `UID`.

Try something like this:

```
try{
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

    outputStream.writeBytes("screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/MyVideo.mp4\n");
    outputStream.flush();

    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    su.waitFor();
}catch(IOException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Comment: Some versions of `su` will take the arguments on the command line, so you could e.g. `exec("su -c screenrecord /sdcard/foo.mp4")`.

Comment: is it possible to do the recording without root access?

Comment: big thank you for this snippet, and just to add what I missed in this post is that **there has to be an `\n`** at the end of the command string

Comment: it has returned below error.

Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: You need to have `su` in your execution path `/system/bin`. @Hendra

Comment: i run these code and get `su error=13, permission denied`, does it need root privilege?

Comment: it only works with root access ? does any method work without root ?

Answer (score 35):

A modification of the code by @CarloCannas:

```
public static void sudo(String...strings) {
    try{
        Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

        for (String s : strings) {
            outputStream.writeBytes(s+"\n");
            outputStream.flush();
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outputStream.flush();
        try {
            su.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        outputStream.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(You are welcome to find a better place for *outputStream.close()*)

Usage example:

```
private static void suMkdirs(String path) {
    if (!new File(path).isDirectory()) {
        sudo("mkdir -p "+path);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
To get the result (the output to stdout), use:

```
public static String sudoForResult(String...strings) {
    String res = "";
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream response = null;
    try{
        Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
        response = su.getInputStream();

        for (String s : strings) {
            outputStream.writeBytes(s+"\n");
            outputStream.flush();
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outputStream.flush();
        try {
            su.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        res = readFully(response);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Closer.closeSilently(outputStream, response);
    }
    return res;
}
public static String readFully(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length = 0;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return baos.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

The utility to silently close a number of Closeables ([Soсket may be no Closeable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29825740/755804)) is:

```
public class Closer {
// closeAll()
public static void closeSilently(Object... xs) {
    // Note: on Android API levels prior to 19 Socket does not implement Closeable
    for (Object x : xs) {
        if (x != null) {
            try {
                Log.d("closing: "+x);
                if (x instanceof Closeable) {
                    ((Closeable)x).close();
                } else if (x instanceof Socket) {
                    ((Socket)x).close();
                } else if (x instanceof DatagramSocket) {
                    ((DatagramSocket)x).close();
                } else {
                    Log.d("cannot close: "+x);
                    throw new RuntimeException("cannot close "+x);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.x(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You sir, rock. Yes.

Answer (score 5):

```
Process p;
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params[0]);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(line + "\n");
        p.waitFor();
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String response = output.toString();
return response;
```

Comment: I am not able to launch application using above command executer `am start -n com.qop.tabletApp.activity.ConfigurationAndSetup`

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but it will benefit someone. You can use the `sh` command in the `exec()` method.
Here is my example:

```
try {
    File workingDirectory = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath());
    Process shProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh", null, workingDirectory);
    try{
        PrintWriter outputExec = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(shProcess.getOutputStream()));
        outputExec.println("PATH=$PATH:/data/data/com.bokili.server.nginx/files;export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.bokili.server.nginx/files;nginx;exit;");
        outputExec.flush();
    } catch(Exception ignored){  }
    shProcess.waitFor();
} catch (IOException ignored) {
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    try{ Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); }catch(Exception ignored){}
} catch (Exception ignored) { }
```

What have I done with this?
First I call the `shell`, then I change (set) the necessary environments in it, and finally I start my nginx with it.

This works on unrooted devices too.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

another solution launch app from android linux shell:

```
am start -n [your package]/.MainActivity
```

according
[Launch an app from Android shell terminal](https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2015/05/launch-app-from-android-shell-terminal.html)

Answer (score 0):

[@18446744073709551615's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654728/14073678) is great, but there is a much simpler way to
use it if the android phone is rooted with newer version of magisk
which is to use `--command` option to run one time command, this makes the code much simpler and less bug prone

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public static List<String> sudo(String[] cmd) {
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String[] fullCmd = ArrayUtils.addAll(new String[]{"su", "--command"}, cmd);
            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fullCmd);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(su.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(su.getErrorStream()));

            String s;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
                res.add(s);
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
                res.add(s);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
}
```