# Android Studio's type checker is complaining that Runtime.exec() is returning a Java process rather than an Android process

Tags: android, android-runtime

I have the following code:

```
try {
    String command = "ps";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Android Studio is now issuing the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: java.lang.Process cannot be converted to android.os.Process
```

I could have sworn this code was working the last time I looked at it. I tried invalidating caches and restarting to no avail. Can someone point out what's going on?

Comment: `Process` and `Runtime` are not the same thing.
Try replacing `Process` by `Runtime`

Comment: @SylvainGIROD so all the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android     are incorrect?

Comment: You've just got the wrong `Process` class Imported. `Runtime#exec()` does return a `java.lang.Process`.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks!