# run shell command programmatically (not rooted)

Tags: android, adb

I need to run adb command to go to sdcard folder. I tried:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /sdcard");
```

But got error at runtime:

```
Cannot run program "cd": error=13, Permission denied
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": error=13, Permission denied
```

Is there anyway to run the adb command programmatically without root the device?

(I have already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android), but it is for rooted device.)

Comment: While adb can also run shell commands, adb and shell are not interchangeable. Your question has nothing to do with adb (Android debug bridge).

Comment: updated my question.