# Permission denied when trying to run NMAP process on Android using Java code of Android app

Tags: java, android-studio, cmd, processbuilder, nmap

i'm trying to create an app android to run nmap commands from terminal and shows the result in the app

I am trying to run this line of code:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nmap  ");           
    BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String s;
    // reading output stream of the command  
    while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.d("res", s);
    }
 } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nmap":
>   error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execute shell command from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error then you will see the message **Permission Denied**. Your android app doesn't execute in the root level. You need root level privilege to run that command.

You should do something like:

```
Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
```

Use the `DataOutputStream` object to write the `nmap` command out the shell and then read the response using an `InputStream`

You can find the code code to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android)

Comment: i used the " su" but it's the same error Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied

Comment: @Rachid can you please update your question with your new attempt?

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied