# How to pass command to termux using dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, termux

I just want to command to Termux with a stream in Xamarin.Forms. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android) is how to I can execute shell but for passing command to termux I have qustion
I included Java libraries to my xamarin-forms project to exectute shell to android app
here is the code:

```
                Java.Lang.Process su = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("com.Termux");
            Java.IO.DataOutputStream outputStream = new Java.IO.DataOutputStream(su.OutputStream);
            outputStream.WriteBytes("nano demo.cpp");
            outputStream.Flush();
```

I try this and it isn't working and throwing an exception :

`'Cannot run program "com.Termux": error=2, No such file or directory'`

what should I pass to `.Exec()` constructor parameter to open termux and wait for command?

Comment: Termux is an app, not an Android OS utility

Comment: @Jason
Do you mean that I want to do is impossible?

Comment: I have no idea.  See the linked duplicate question.  There are methods to call other apps, but they are different than executing OS commands