# Why Can't I Execute Shell Commands from My Android App?

Tags: java, android, adb

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to execute a command from a Java Android app on Android 14 rooted device. The command in question is:

```
PS C:\Users\gmmo> adb shell "cat /sdcard/myfile.txt"
hello world!
PS C:\Users\gmmo>
```

However, each attempt to execute the aforementioned command programmatically leads to the following error:

```
command = "cat /sdcard/myfile.txt"
output = "Error executing command. Exit code: 1"
```

I have referred to a thread on Stack Overflow for guidance, but I am unable to identify the problem. The thread can be found here:

[execute shell command from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android)

Here is the code snippet I have been working with:

```
    public static String executeCommand(String command) {
        try {
            // Create a process to execute the command
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            // Get the input stream to read the output
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            if (exitCode == 0) {
                return output.toString();
            } else {
                return "Error executing command. Exit code: " + exitCode;
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }


    public static void testShellCmd() {
        String command = "cat /sdcard/myfile.txt";
        String output = executeCommand(command);
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Among other possible problems, your app does not have access to that file.

Comment: how do I make it have access to it? it is in the sdcard, it should have it I'd guess.

Comment: Every app is running on an own user account with app specific permission. The adb shell is running on a special user account that has some more permissions as most apps. Therefore adb shell commands are often not working when executed from within an app. Just use the regular Java way via scoped storage to access files on the sdcard/shared storage.

Comment: Can you show me an example of "regular Java way via scoped storage"? I don't know what this is.